# Refactoring the following code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models blog and comment. Blog contains multiple comments, comment can only belong to 1 blog.

For showing the API like 
blog/2/comment/1

I have to use the following code inside the comment controller

```
def show
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
    @comments = @blog.comments
    @comment = @comments[params[:id].to_i - 1]
  end
```

I feel this code is quite akward, especially the last one `@comments[params[:id].to_i - 1]`. I have to convert parameter id to integer, then change to 0 based array index. Any refactoring can happen here

Comment: yeah, it's not clear at all what this code does. Is it to make each post/blog run its own comment counter? Why not just use id field of the comments table?

Comment: yes, I need to make each post run its own comment counter

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean make it look more "Rails"? Like this?

```
def show
     @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
     @comment = @blog.comments.find params[:id]
end
```

As per OP's comment. Your transformation is **necessary**. However, you can avoid loading the entire set of comments and only take the one you need.

```
@comment = @blog.comments.offset(params[:id].to_i - 1).limit(1)
```

Comment: There is a difference between using `find` and using `[]` to access an element. `find` with `0` will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception while `[]` with `0` will fetch the very first element.

Comment: it does not meet my design. say blog/2/comment/1 should return the first comment of blog 2, however this implementio return null is first comment if on blog 1.

Comment: Yokay. Maybe you should update your question to clearly indicate this requirement.

Comment: @Adam Lee, I added something to my answer, if you are interested.